# How to make a select query using a local variable in SQLite on Swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite

In Swift, if you want to make a query from a local variable it is done by 'selectedButton'. So how is it possible in SQLite?

```
{
    var selectedButton = 1;
    let dbPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("practise2015", ofType:"sqlite3")
    let db = FMDatabase(path: dbPath)
    if db.open(){
        let categoryLevelID = try! db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `LEVEL` WHERE CATEGORY_ID = " +  selectedButton, values: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of variable is `db`? This could be susceptible to SQL injection- it's best to use placeholders like `?` and bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do something like this?

```
let categoryLevelID = try! db.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM LEVEL WHERE CATEGORY_ID = \(selectedButton.tag)", values: nil)
```

actuall you can't just pass a UIButton as an argument, you need some String, Int or Double value. Category_id sounds like an Int to me, so I guess you have the correct category_id in your UIButton as it's Tag

But you should do queries by using data binding anyway.  Take a look at this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123579/sqlite-tutorial-swift

Or this one: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iOS_8_Application_using_Swift_and_FMDB

Comment: This is a terrible practice. Never build query strings this way. Properly bind the values into the query.

Comment: @rmaddy good advice, but that's actually what I said. My solution provides a quick and dirty way to see if it works + 2 links to show how it should be done.